# Can't change 'From' email address when I send a Single Email or Mass Email

Tags: email, email-template

A user is not able to change the "From" email address when sending an email in Salesforce UI from standard/custom objects and even the global publisher actions. The field "From" is empty and greyed out as following :
[image]

This behaviour is specific to two particular users with different profiles. Other users with same or different profiles and perm sets are able to chose between the defined org-wide address or their own email address.
I have spent the whole day comparing between profiles/perm sets, searching online, checked email deliverability to "All email", access to Task/Activity, "Send email" permissions ... but with no luck. I have also repeated the steps in the following [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382694&type=1) with no success as well.

What might be the issue ?

Comment: Have you granted access to the Org-Wide Email Addresses to those users via Permission Sets as per [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_manage_orgwide_email_addresses.htm&type=5)

Comment: Yes access is granted for all profiles in the org not by permission set.
N.B: this user can't even select his own address as a sending address so it is not just related to org-wide addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved with Salesforce support. The cause is that there was two active connection with Office 365 one at Org level and the other at User level. It is solved by removing the user level connected account by following these steps :

1. Click on user profile picture then on "Settings"
2. Go to Connected Accounts > Email and Calendar Accounts
3. Remove the user level connected account

[image]